# Trying to get key in a foreach loop to work using blade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

if I use `{{$node[0]->url}}` then Laravel's templating engine dislays the correct result but I can not figure out how to display all using the @for $i=0 within a @foreach loop this is what I have in my routes file

```
$oReturn = new stdClass();
        $fid='endpoints';//sample fid

        $url = 'http://localhost:5493/sdata/$system/registry/'.$fid;

        $xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
        foreach($xml->xpath("//sdata:payload") as $entry) {
            // xpath here must be from payload to endPoint--type
            $content = $entry->xpath("./sdata:endPoint--type");

            foreach($content as $c) {
                // Make set of children with prefix sdata
                $nodes = $c->children('sdata', true);

            }

// add parsed data to the array
            $oReturn->entry[] = $nodes;

        }
        return View::make('index', compact('oReturn'));
```

and this is what I have tried in my view file

```
@for($i=0; $i < 4; $i++)
@endfor
@foreach ($oReturn as $node)
   <li>{{$node[$i]->url}}</li>
@endforeach
```

sorry here is the complete print_r result

```
Array ( [oReturn] => stdClass Object 
( [entry] => Array 
    ( 
        [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [description] => Sage 50 Accounts [protocol] => http [host] => base_3 [applicationName] => accounts50 [contractName] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) [dataSetName] => - [url] => http://base_3:5493/sdata/accounts50 [isBrowsable] => true [aliveStamp] => 2015-11-06T23:31:10.031+00:00 ) 
        [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [endPointType] => dataSet [applicationName] => accounts50 [contractName] => GCRM [dataSetName] => Enter Your Company Name [url] => http://base_3:5493/sdata/accounts50/GCRM/{C22ACA13-3C4C-4E33-A584-CD99BD3002A6} ) 
        [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [endPointType] => dataSet [applicationName] => accounts50 [contractName] => GCRM [dataSetName] => Enter Your Company Name [url] => http://base_3:5493/sdata/accounts50/GCRM/{FF476636-D4AF-4191-BDE4-891EDA349A68} ) 
        [3] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [endPointType] => dataSet [applicationName] => accounts50 [contractName] => GCRM [dataSetName] => Enter Your Company Name [url] => http://base_3:5493/sdata/accounts50/GCRM/{C62A13D5-3FFE-43B4-9DAF-38F9055A83C7} ) 
        [4] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [description] => GCRM Contract [endPointType] => contract [protocol] => http [host] => base_3 [applicationName] => accounts50 [contractName] => GCRM [dataSetName] => - [url] => http://base_3:5493/sdata/accounts50/GCRM [aliveStamp] => 2015-11-06T23:31:11.062+00:00 ) 
    ) 
) 
) 1
```

Answer (score 73, accepted):

The simple answer is that `foreach` in Blade works the same as a regular PHP `foreach`. You should be able to do something like:

```
@foreach ($nodes as $node)
    <li>{{ $node->url }}</li>
@endforeach
```

If you need access to the array key value for each node:

```
@foreach ($nodes as $key => $node)
    <li>{{ $key }}: {{ $node->url }}</li>
@endforeach
```

However, I think the problem may not be with your Blade syntax, but with the way you created your input variables. Given the way you created `$oReturn` in the code above, it won't have the properties you appear to be expecting. To illustrate, here's a simplified version of what you appear to be creating:

```
// initialize your return variable 
$oReturn = new stdClass();

// create a dummy array <sdata:x> nodes,
// to simulate $nodes = $c->children('sdata', true);
$node = new SimpleXMLElement('<sdata:x/>');
$nodes = [ $node, $node, $node ];

// simulate adding nodes to the array of entries 
$oReturn->entry[] = [ $node, $node, $node ];

// print out the resulting structure
print_r( compact( 'oReturn' ) );
```

would return:

```
Array(
    [oReturn] => stdClass Object
        (
            [entry] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object()
                            [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object()
                            [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object()
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

So when you do `@foreach ($oReturn as $node)` the value of `$node` would be the `entry[]` array, which has a single element, that is an array of nodes. It is not clear from your input that these nodes even have `url` elements. If you did want to loop through the nodes you'd have to do something like:

```
@foreach ($oReturn->entry[0] as $node)
    <li>{{ $node->url }}</li>
@endforeach
```

Does this make sense? I think you need to rethink your creation of `$oReturn`.

#### Update

Given feedback below and the output of your `print_r` statement above, the following should work:

```
@foreach ($oReturn->entry as $node)
    <li>{{ (string) $node->url }}</li>
@endforeach
```

The `(string)` casts the result of `$node->url` to string. Otherwise PHP may treat it as some kind of object. `SimpleXMLElement` can be weird.

Comment: Your right this is what I get"[0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [description] => Sage 50 Accounts [protocol] => http [host] => base_3 [applicationName] => accounts50 [contractName] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) [dataSetName] => - [url] => http://base_3:5493/sdata/accounts50 [isBrowsable] => true [aliveStamp] => 2015-11-06T23:31:10.031+00:00 ) " and I have 4 of them which I am trying to display the [url] segment in the view

Comment: can you suggest how you might solve this problem as I have tried several approaches all of which fail when I try passing the result to the view I know I am doing something wrong but what?

Comment: How might you  use the above code  in {{Form::select}} to give the url as options